# Remote powershell не возвращает значения вложенных свойств

Tags: powershell, exchange

Мне нужно получать информацию о общедоступных папках с удаленного Exchange сервера и для этого я использую remote powershell. Но есть одна проблема - remote powershell приводит все свойства возвращаемых объектов к строковому виду:

```
$mailFolders = Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri:$uri –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential:$creds -ScriptBlock {
    Get-MailPublicFolder "\imdev-ie-025-pf1\sublevel1\sublevel2";
};

$mailFolders | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses
```

Этот код вернет следующее:

```
smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
```

Но если выполнить этот командлет локально на exchange сервере, то результат будет примерно таким:

```
Get-MailPublicFolder "\imdev-ie-025-pf1\sublevel1\sublevel2" | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses

SmtpAddress        : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
AddressString      : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025-2.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp

SmtpAddress        : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
AddressString      : sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
ProxyAddressString : smtp:sublevel2@imdev-ie-025.com
Prefix             : SMTP
IsPrimaryAddress   : False
PrefixString       : smtp
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи как можно получать объекты целиком со всеми значениями? Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте использовать select в одном -scriptBlock, есть вероятность, что он получает объект со свойствами, а переслать свойства не даёт, и поэтому селект после получения результата работает только на заголовки  $mailFolders = Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri:$uri –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential:$creds -ScriptBlock {
    Get-MailPublicFolder "\imdev-ie-025-pf1\sublevel1\sublevel2" | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses;
};

Comment: @paulo-berezini примерно так и сделал. Сначала получаю коллекцию всех паблик фолдеров, потом для каждого получаю EmailAddresses. Минус такого подхода, что для каждого фолдера нужно делать новый вызов. Почему Remote Powershell сериализует только до одного уровня вложенности я так и не разобрался. Возможно это как-то настраивается.

Comment: я думаю это не настраивается, так работает powershell, в любом случае вам следует обратиться в тех потдержку по этому вопросу